# PHP Array with date/time and duration for highchart

Tags: php

So first here's Fiddle of what I am trying to achieve in the end:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQXvR/)

To do so I need to get values from three different tables: ok_part, reject and stoppage.

As for stoppage, the table structure looks like this:

[image: Stoppage table structure]

The x Axis of my chart are one hour gaps, the first x Axis is always time 8 hours ago and the last one time from now to next full hour.

I've managed to put together ok_part and reject arrays for highchart.

```
class GraphCalc() {
  .....
  /* calculate time */
  function CalculateTime($diff, $form) {

    $new = new DateTime();
    $new->modify($diff);
    return $form != 0 ? $new->format('Y-m-d H:00') : $new->format('Y-m-d');
  }

  function GraphInterval() {

    $time = strtotime($this->CalculateTime('-8 hours', 1)); // calling function to get time 8 hours ago
    $now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:00'));

    /* looping through time (8 hours ago to now) */
    for ($i = $time, $j = $i + 3600; $i <= $now; $i += 3600, $j += 3600) {

        /* puts together array for x Axis */
        $this->xAxis_array[] =  "'".date('H:00', $i).' - '.date('H:00', $j)."'";

        /* queries to sum ok parts and rejects according to time */
        $ok_part_sum[] = MouldingPart::find(
            array(
                'select' => 'SUM(amount) as ok_qty', 
                'conditions' => array(
                    'moulding_product_id IN (?) AND date >= ? AND date <= ?', 
                    $this->product_id, 
                    date('Y-m-d H:00', $i), 
                    date('Y-m-d H:00', $j)
                )
            )
        )->ok_qty;
        $reject_part_sum[] = MouldingReject::find(
            array(
                'select' => 'SUM(amount) as reject_qty', 
                'conditions' => array(
                    'moulding_product_id IN (?) AND date >= ? AND date <= ?', 
                    $this->product_id, 
                    date('Y-m-d H:00', $i), 
                    date('Y-m-d H:00', $j)
                )
            )
        )->reject_qty;
    }

    /* looping through ok_part and reject arrays to add 0 where there's no value */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ok_part_sum); $i++) { 
        $this->chart_ok_array[] = $ok_part_sum[$i] == '' ? 0 : $ok_part_sum[$i];
        $this->chart_reject_array[] = $reject_part_sum[$i] == '' ? 0 : $reject_part_sum[$i];
    }
  }

  function xAxis() {
    /* return x Axis values */
    return implode(', ',$this->xAxis_array);
  }

  function yAxisValues() {
    /* put together arrays for highchart */
    $chart_data[] = "{data: [".implode(", ",$this->chart_ok_array)."], name: 'OK', color: '#89A54E'}";
    $chart_data[] = "{data: [".implode(", ",$this->chart_reject_array)."], name: 'PRAAGID', color: '#AA4643'}";


    return $chart_data;
  }
}
```

I've would like help to get a solution for stoppage data. Stoppage has two dates that need to be considered: start_date and end_date. Based on the x Axis and stoppage dates I need to calculate the duration. Sometimes I could probably use the duration field, but I think it is easier to avoid it and just calculate it on the fly.

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve with stoppage:

Let's say x Axis is 05:00 - 06:00 then stoppage duration should be 59 minutes, because there is an entry in stoppage table with start_date 2013-09-05 05:01:00 and end_date 2013-09-05 09:00:00, but I can't use the end date of stoppage table value, because I need to use the x axis value which is 06:00.

I hope you get an idea of what I am trying to achieve, it is really hard to explain it.

The data in stoppage table might vary as well. In one hour there might be multiple stoppages. Let's say x Axis is 08:00 - 09:00 and in table there are three stoppages:

start_date: 07:54  end_date: 08:15
start_date: 08:19  end_date: 08:38
start_date: 08:45  end_date: 09:47
So the duration from 08:00 - 09:00 should be 49 minutes.

Please help me with this, I've been stuck with this for days now.. I tried to explain it as good as I could, but I bet it's still confusing.

In the end I would like to get an array for highchart, like I have with ok_part and reject.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing... You could try to make a picture (or whatever) of your desired chart maybe ? Do you always want the bars to be 100% ? Does your question is how to get an array with `php` of the `stoppage` series ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. So... are you trying to assemble some data into bins by time range, but you're having trouble because the stoppage table has already collected some data into different bins?

Comment: I think you want us to complete your `GraphInterval` function ?

Comment: @Brewal The desired chart is the fiddle I shared. I think it's okay if the bars are 100% all the time. Yea, my question is how to get the php array of the stoppage series. It would be nice if you could help me with the GraphInterval function :)

Comment: @alexg I am trying to complete the chart, but I don't know how to collect the stoppage data into an array.

Comment: Well, that was hard, but I think I finally understood what you are trying to do and got this to work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html#idp52185520) that will substract the `end_date` with the `start_date` :

```
$stoppage_part_sum[] = MouldingStoppage::find(
    array(
        'select' => 'SUM(
            ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                MINUTE,
                IF(end_date > \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $j).'\', \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $j).'\', end_date),
                IF(start_date < \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $i).'\', \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $i).'\', start_date)
            ))
        ) as stoppage_qty', 
        'conditions' => array(
            'moulding_product_id IN (?) AND end_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?', 
            $this->product_id, 
            date('Y-m-d H:00', $i), 
            date('Y-m-d H:00', $j)
        )
    )
)->stoppage_qty;
```

The `IF(end_date > ...)` and `IF(start_date < ...)`is to take only the time into the current window. It will then use this :

```
start_date: 08:00 end_date: 08:15
start_date: 08:19 end_date: 08:38
start_date: 08:45 end_date: 09:00
```

Then you just `TIMESTAMPDIFF` `end_date` and `start_date` and `SUM` them.

Note the condition to match the concerned "stoppages". (`start_date` < **j** and `end_date` > **i**)

**[The demo sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f7825/11)**

Try to change the dates in data to watch the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm. I just can't thank you enough.

Comment: There is a small typo in the code, I compared the sqlFiddle and your code given here. In the second IF statement IF(start_date < \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $i).'\', \''.date('Y-m-d H:00', $i).'\', start_date). The variable in both date should be $i. But once again, thank you :).